What majority age is taken into consideration when travelling from country to country?
Multiple countries have differing ages, and citizens are considered to have reached the majority age and thus can travel without parental authorization. In most countries, the age is 18, but in the country I live in, it's 19, and if you are below that age, then you will need parental authorization to travel from my country to another one.
But what if I traveled to a country like the UK, where the majority age is 18, from my country and I needed parental authorization to do so, now I'm in the UK and planning to travel to a country like Malaysia, where the majority age is also 18.
Will I need parental authorization or not?
Additional Info:
I am 18 years old
My country is Algeria
The country I will travel from is the UK
The country i will travel to is Malaysia for 60 days

For interest, what is your country?

@RussellMcMahon - Could be  Algeria, Canada (British Columbia, New Brunswick, Newfoundland and Labrador, Northwest Territories, Nova Scotia, Nunavut, Yukon), South Korea, United States (Alabama, Nebraska)

@MichaelHarvey considering parental approval requirement, less likely to be Canada and US.

Each country has their own rules and that's the rules they apply when you interact with them.
Travelling from country A to B typically (but not always) involves two independent interactions: exiting A and entering B. If A requires you to have parental consent and you don't have it, they won't let you leave. If B requires you to have parental consent and you don't have it, they will turn you around at the border and sent you back to A  (regardless of what rules apply in A).
There are nuances to this, but in general this is how it works: you need to satisfy the requirements of BOTH countries.
This being said: when our kids were minors (in any country!) they crossed the Atlantic quite a few a times on their own without any type of formal or informal "parental consent" document and no one ever gave a hoot.

@ClioProto Not all countries restrict a minor's freedom to travel to the same extent, and many countries treat a 16 year old differently than a 8 year old (even if both are minors). I travelled alone between Canada and China (and with U.S. stopovers sometimes) when I was a minor teenager in the early and mid 2010s without problem...

...Except one time a hotel referred me to the police because I don't have a Chinese ID, then the police called a relative (2000km away) as a matter of procedure for minors. Airlines didn't care once I was over the age of mandatory unaccompanied minor: apparently American airlines do require that until age 14, but Chinese and Canadian airlines usually only require it for 11 and under.

That said, immigration authorities do inquire about my address/place of stay, and they probably would treat someone with family presence in the country (even if very distant) differently than a child travelling alone for tourism/adventure.

@ClioProto: I tried to answer this as good as I could for the "general" case. The only way to get a better answer is to make it specific: from where to where for what purpose and duration at what age? There is no "one size fits all" answer. If you need better, please edit your questions with the details or ask a new question.  Without getting very specific we can't tell you what form of parental permission (if any) you might need.

@Fe2O3: in 2013 my then 14-years-old daughter flew alone from Canada to the US, she cleared US immigration, flew domestic in the US, and then internationally from the US to Argentina. She did have a notarized parental authorization, but no airline employee nor immigration officer (be it in Canada, USA, or Argentina) asked for it. I would consider both Air Canada and United "reputable".

Will they really turn an unaccompanied minor back (as opposed to looking for a parent, alerting the authorities of the country you come from, etc.)? Seems to defeat the purpose.

@Relaxed: these are more or less the same things. "turning around" is a fairly involved process and not just an officer saying "Sorry, you can't enter, go back" (although some a$$hole US CBP officer tried this on me as a scare tactic, when I was travelling perfectly legally with 3 small kids in tow). In many place there is nowhere to go my yourself, the the authorities will do make paper work and arrangements for you to be returned.

hey @Hilmar i added more details into the question including what is my nationality and the country i will travel from and to and also the duration of the stay in the"to" country thanks for pointing out the lack of details

@ClioProto: how old are you ? If you are 18 already, you should be fine. You are an adult in the UK and in Malaysia. But some of this is always up to the mood of the immigration officer, so if you are in doubt, just bring the darn form with you (unless there is a reason you can't).

If you are interested in a specific situation, you may ask at Law.SE, where they would give you an accurate answer. To complete @Hilmar's excellent answers, most countries follow (at least) two main principles for their law:

Territoriality principle: the law applies on their territory, to everybody (citizens of the country or not).
Nationality principle: the law applies to all their nationals, everywhere (on their territory and outside). For example, drug and gambling are illegal in Korean law, and you can sometimes hear in the news about Korean nationals being arrested when they arrive at the airport for drug use or gambling.

There may be situations not covered above (IIRC, criticizing the King of Thailand is a crime, everywhere and for everyone, and the Thai police watches over the net to find offenders). In case of doubt, ask a lawyer.
Therefore, if you are a national of country A traveling from country A to country B, you have to take into account the laws of both countries.
Note that this is not restricted to age. For example, the marriage of a same-sex couple, while being perfectly legal in country A, may not be recognized in country B.

i have edited my question to include more info on the countries that will be in play in my situation what do you think now about this specific situation?
